# xjc and XSD choice

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

When I run xjc to generate a Java type representing this XSD snippet:

```
  <xs:complexType name="fileUploadRequest">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="path" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="file" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I get a class that's indistinguishable from what it would have been if I'd specified a `sequence` with optional elements instead.

I want a type with a little bit of intelligence, that'll let me have at most 1 element of my choice at a time.  If I invoke the generated `setFile` method for example, it should make the path null.  Is there some plugin I can use for what seems like an obvious requirement of a code generator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**binding.xml**

You can use the following external binding file to generate the type of property you are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          version="2.1">
    <globalBindings choiceContentProperty="true"/>
</bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

The binding file is referenced using the `-b` flag.

```
xjc -b binding.xml schema.xsd
```

**Generated Property**

Now the following property will be generated:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "path", type = String.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "file", type = byte[].class)
})
protected Object pathOrFile;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html

Comment: OK that looks great functionally, thanks very much. I imagine you distinguish between path vs. file by checking the type of `pathOrFile` (e.g., `if (pathOrFile instanceof String)`). Right? How does that work when some of the elements of the choice are of the same type?

Comment: @blueimpb - When the elements are of the same type the result is wrapped in a `JAXBElement` to preserve the element information.